# How to avoid showing file name in batch output file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I am running command,**

```
Find /C /I "pass" "log.txt" > output.txt
```

**output am getting,**

```
---------- LOG.TXT: 2
```

Getting this output because, there is two time the word "pass" comes in `log.txt` file.

**expected output,**

```
2
```

I don't wanna the file name to be included in output file. I need only the count. I remember something called /NoLogo command that works But, donno the exact command or where to use it. Kindly help me.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look over the answer I provided below. Circling back around to see about closing the loop if nothing else and this as an FYI.... https://i.imgur.com/OZho1tT.png

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to omit the file name within the output of the [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) command when getting a count for line matches without needing to loop and using delims and such is to. . .

#### 1. By redirecting the file over to the find command to have its lines searched using that method of [command redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) e.g. `command < filename`

```
  Find /C /I "pass" < output.txt
```

#### 2.  Use the [type](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command against the file and then pipe that over to the `find` command to use that method of [command redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

```
 type output.txt | Find /C /I "pass"
```

#### Example Output (two matching lines)

```
2
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Command Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

  > ```
  >    command < filename        Type a text file and pass the text to command
  >
  >    commandA  |  commandB     Pipe the output from commandA into commandB
  > ```
- [How to find the number of occurrences of a string in file using windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307187/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-file-using-windows-command)

Comment: I believe these two methods do the exact same thing essentially. Maybe there are some batch experts that know otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

Could be someting like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 Delims=:" %%a in ('Find /C /I "pass" "log.txt"') do for /f %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%b>output.txt
```